# Conditional formatting date and text combined

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Of all the possible combinations I have tried so far, every single one results in the same "there is a problem with this formula" error message.

This is what I am trying:
Conditional formatting -> new rule -> use a formula to determine which cells to format:
=AND(B$1=TODAY(),B2="x")

[image]

The goal is to let those cells that contain "x" AND are below the current date, turn a different color. Either one of those conditions on itself does work, but there is an unknown issue with the combination which I hope you can give a hint to figure out.

EDIT:
The error turned out to be caused by the regional settings, where instead of "," an ";" should be used in the AND formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is correct.  You need to cheek if the issue is not related to the PC regional settings. You might have to use `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: @Miles The formula is correct and there is no error on my side. If you copy my formula instead of yours (even though they are the same), do you still get an error?

Comment: @Miles Also cheek if the issue is not related to the PC regional settings. You might have to use `;` instead of `,`.

Comment: Yes it was due to the regional settings! I wonder how many hours those have managed to squander. Thank you incredibly much for saving my day and weekend!

Comment: Since it is not your answer, but the comment below that fixed the issue, how can I mark it as solved?

Comment: @Miles I have edited the answer to reflect the comment.